# Calling a web page via Inappbrowser(IOS) is slow. How is it possible using Cordova WkWebView?

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, mobile-application

I have created  cordova app (ios)that calls a web page via inappbrowser. But due to the decrease in speed in ios, i googled and found about WKWebView. I have installed all the plugins for WkWebview, but I want to know how to call a web page using that? 
In Inappbrowser i used this for calling the webpage,

```
   var url = 'http://google.com'; 
   var target = '_blank';
   var options = "location=no,closebuttoncaption=exit,toolbar=no";
   var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

   ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('loadloaderror', loaderrorCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);

   function loadstartCallback(event) {
  console.log('Loading started: '  + event.url)
  }

  function loadstopCallback(event) {
  console.log('Loading finished: ' + event.url)
  }

  function loaderrorCallback(error) {
  console.log('Loading error: ' + error.message)
  }

   function exitCallback() {
  console.log('Browser is closed...')
  }
```

Similarly I want to know is there a way to call the web page via wkwebview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I've fixed the remaining known issues with my fork of the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin, which I've rewritten to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView (as the original InappBrowser plugin does), and published it as [`cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview) so:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview
```

Comment: Isn't that only for android ??

Comment: No, it's for both Android and iOS. Hence the iOS WKWebView rewrite.

Comment: I'll try...Speed is the main criteria that i need, is it worth it?

Comment: This version of Cordova InAppBrowser uses WKWebView instead of UIWebView, which is what you asked in your question. You can try it and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: In my Ionic app i am using UIWebView. If i load dropbox auth screen using inAppBrowser it now working properly. If I upgrade UIWebView to WKWebView it working properly. Plz tell me any solution. I have also add question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222894/ionic-inappbrowser-not-working-on-ios-uiwebview but no response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing.  Create  a native controller with XIB and create a WKWebview their. Write a cordova call and pass your url to native function. And then load the url in the WKWebview. Dont use the the inappBrowser.

For example. 
Your WKWebViewController.h File

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WKWebViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlToBeLoaded;

@end
```

Your WKWebViewController.m File

```
#import "WKWebViewController.h"

@interface WKWebViewController ()

@end


@implementation WKWebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToBeLoaded];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

Apart from this you have to write a plugin class and there define a method which you will call from javascript. From the plugin class you have to load the above Controller

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Is it like in this ?                                                                        https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

Comment: You can refer this link for how to  make a plugin in Cordova

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html

Comment: Actually this is done for native apps right? I build this using cordova platform

Comment: No. For Cordova also we can write native plugins.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The latest version of cordova-plugin-inappbrowser allows the use of wkwebview as an option which will improve performance for iOS 12:

Add `"usewkwebview=yes"` to your options when trying to open the inAppBrowser. Be sure to have WKWebView engine plugin installed in your project.

Documentation:

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen

---

The performance improved for me after using the latest version of the plugin. It is especially noticeable for devices using iOS 12:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/271

> contains some major changes, but with [UIWebView now deprecated in iOS 12](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?changes=_6&language=objc), then getting this plugin to support WKWebView seems now to be a higher priority.

Here is the approved PR for this feature to be used in the official plugin (person making the PR is the author of the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview referenced in the other answer). You can install the latest plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#CB-7179
```

And you will still need to install apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine just like the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview from https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

Also if you're having issues making a package using these plugins, be sure to not have conflicting plugins:

Remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview for cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (using the version provided from the CB-7179 PR listed above)

Remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview (comes installed for ionic 3) for cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

tl;dr:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#CB-7179

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

I would keep an eye out for the next release of the cordova-plugin-inappbrowse on github seeing how the PR has been approved and merged. When the new release comes out, you should just use the latest cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. As of writing this, the latest release (3.0.0) was in April.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/releases